# MatTable with row click event for extra details in Angular 5+ (with bootstrap 4)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

Angular MatTable with row click event for extra details

[image]

I want create design using angular Material with Bootstrap4 to display student information (i have successfully completed) but when i click on row i need to show some extra details of that student (row event also completed, i can populate details) but not able to display in right side table (mine is showing below the table). i have used grid layout for same but no success.

Please suggest example or documentation

Comment: Please add your code to better understand your question

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, vijay. Not a picture. The code. Use codesandbox.io if you need a multi-file node based environment.